# Renderizar vários componentes baseado em um número

Tags: javascript, react

Tenho um componente em ReactJs e preciso renderizar o componente `<FaRegStar key="1" size="30px" />` baseado no map `list.stars`. Não sei como poderia fazer isso, alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
const User = () => {

const users = loadUsers();

return (
    <>
        {users.map(list =>
            <Container key={list.id}>
                <ProfileImg src={list.icon} alt="" />
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <p>{list.name}</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <FaRegStar key="1" size="30px" />
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </Container>
        )}
    </>
)
}
```

Exemplo:

Caso list.stars seja 2 ele deverá renderizar isso

```
<FaRegStar key="1" size="30px" />
<FaRegStar key="1" size="30px" />
```

Nesse caso seria renderizado duas estrelas

Answer (score 0):

O ideal é vc passar a props pra dentro de FaRegStar e pegar elas dentro do component

```
const style = {
        width: this.props.size,
}

return <div style={style}>
        Hello
  </div>
```

Comment: Olá Pedro Henrique Cndido Ferreira, este component é de uma lib chamada [react-icons](https://react-icons.netlify.com/#/) e não posso passar as props para dentro dela